# How to deploy a Mono application?

Tags: linux, apache, mono, asp.net-core, kruntime

We want to deploy a MVC5 application which is build on Mono to a Debian server. This server comes from a third party who has a larger web server that can redirect requests via proxies.

In the past I managed to run a small Ruby on Rails server "locally" on the server and have the hosting provider redirect to the ports. Is it possible to do the same thing with Mono?

I heard about the [K runtime for ASP.NET vNext](http://graemechristie.github.io/graemechristie/blog/2014/05/26/asp-dot-net-vnext-on-osx-and-linux/). Can the K runtime also be used for ASP.NET MVC5 applications? And if so how?

Or is it better to ask if the hosting provider can install the [`mod_mono` package](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/)?

Or perhaps I am missing something obvious. I hope you can explain me how to deploy an ASP.NET MVC5 application on Mono to a Linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using lighttpd with the mod_mono module. Came down to copying the files to the server, run a web server locally on the server (just like local xsp4 only then production ready) and configure lighttpd to point a proxy towards it. Similar idea as Mono and nginx as described below.

- Link with script for deploying to Ubuntu with mod_mono and nginx: http://majorsilence.com/news/2014/05/28/ubuntu-14-04-mvc5-with-razor-and-nginx/
- Link for deploying with mod_mono and nginx: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/06/28/setting-up-mono-on-nginx/

Comment: Both links are death, first one ends up in some weird advertisement.

Comment: I am not sure how experiences you are in this, but I am trying to use this setup for my Synology DS213, and I keep running into a 403 issue, it seems like I am not allowed to access the folder, I wonder, do you have any experience with this/ know what this could be?

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/questions/315075/setting-up-mono-asp-net-4-0-on-apache2-ubuntu-virtual-hosts#663217. See the `chmod` on the folder.

Comment: /edit I meant the `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/alduin/www` part of that answer. Let me know if providing the apache user with permission on the folders solves the issue.

Comment: Does this grant permission for all extensions? or only for aspx etc?
Also can I do this in the frontend of a Synology, or do I need to SSH to it?

Comment: It will make the Apache user and group `www-data` owner of the root of your site (so do change the `/home/alduin/www` part to that in the command). An owner has all permissions on all files. You can probably do it via the frontend according to [this topic](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=83269). I would recommend using SSH though since you can do everything via a terminal, you are not limited by the frontend and you can use solutions not specific to Synology (but to Ubuntu).

Comment: The website is running thru Mono and Nginx according to the headers of the website, it can also go to an empty .html file without a problem. I think I need to change some more stuff around thru SSH but I cannot do sudo apt-get or nano. I have to use VI which is very new for me.

Comment: @JpHouten Sounds good. Type `vimtutor` and spend 30 minutes of your time going through the tutorial. You will not regret it.